# Controlling local user voice volume in Discord with setLocalVolume

Tags: discord, volume, voice

I'm trying to programmatically control the relative local volume of users' voices in a Discord channel from a web app.

Discord's Game SDK has a [documented API call](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/blob/master/docs/game_sdk/Discord_Voice.md#setlocalvolume) to control a user's local volume with `VoiceManager.setLocalVolume(userId, level)` from a native game, but Game SDK approvals are currently on-hold and I'm not trying to make a native game.

So, I turned to [Discord browser plugins](https://github.com/mwittrien/BetterDiscordAddons/tree/master/Plugins). On discordapp.com, I can see that a function called `setLocalVolume` is defined, but I don't know how to call it. The Discord API seems to be obfuscated by Webpack.

How can I control local user volume in Discord by tapping into a local Discord process? I'm happy to make and install a custom browser plugin to do this against a web-based discordapp.com page.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm looking to attempt the same thing